# How to disable/enable Micrometer metrics in running microservice

Tags: java, microservices, micrometer, spring-micrometer

How can I disable or enable some of Micrometer's metrics without restarting my microservice? I want to expose an endpoint to change the metrics my application collects.

Comment: Please add some information regarding your chosen metrics backend. Different backends might have different expectations reagrding metrics appearing/disappearing.

Comment: The backend is CloudWatch

Answer (score 1):

**Disable/Enable Scenario**

You want to stop modifying your metric, but keep it on metrics endpoints, so your TSDB system will still scrape it.
There is no such functionality within Micrometer, but you can implement your wrapper around metrics, and put some switcher there.

```java
@Component
public class MetersService {

    ...

    private boolean enableMeters;

    ...

    public void incCounter() {
        if (enableMeters) {
            meterRegistry.counter("my.counter").increment();
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

**Remove Scenario**

If you want remove metric from Micrometer completely, such functionality was added in [1.1.0-rc.1](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/milestone/22) version. Check out [GithHub issue](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/479). So with that version you should be able to do something like this

```java
    public void removeMeter(Meter meter) {
            meterRegistry.remove(meter);
    }
```

Comment: For the Disable/Enable Scenario how do you handle the built-in meters? For the Remove Scenario how do you re-enable meters after disabling them?